# Ionic 3, need help importing custom font (brand new project)

Tags: css, ionic-framework, fonts, sass, ionic3

I'm trying to import a custom icon font called "Picons Thin" into my Ionic project. I put the font formats titled piconsthin-webfont.ttf, piconsthin-webfont.woff, and piconsthin-webfont.woff2 into the `www/assets/fonts` folder, and created a piconsthin-webfont.scss file in the same folder which contains the following:

```
$piconsthin-webfont-font-path: $font-path !default;

@font-face {
  font-family: "piconsthin";
  src: local("piconsthin"),
       url('#{$piconsthin-webfont-font-path}/piconsthin-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('#{$piconsthin-webfont-font-path}/piconsthin-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('#{$piconsthin-webfont-font-path}/piconsthin-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I then went to variables.scss and saw the fonts section at the bottom that was importing roboto and noto-sans, and assumed this was calling the scss files in the fonts folder. So I added my own line:

```
@import "piconsthin-webfont";
```

But that just gives an error in Ionic that says "File to import not found or unreadable: piconsthin-webfont".

I've tried just putting the picons @font-face css into one of the other font scss files that I knew could be found, and I've tried putting the @font-face css into the main src/app/app.scss file, but nothing I do makes the font show up on the front end... what am I doing wrong?? What step am I missing??

Answer (score 1):

Put your fonts in the source folder (src/assets/fonts/CHESSMASTER8000_BOLD.ttf) then connect it in the variables.scss file like this

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Chessmaster-8000";
  font-style: bold;
  src: url('../assets/fonts/CHESSMASTER8000_BOLD.woff');
}
```